# Looking for Passages of harsh criticism in the Shakh

Tags: commentaries

Notwithstanding the fact that the Shakh includes a [passage](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%99_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F#.D7.A9.D7.A4.D7.AA.D7.99_.D7.9B.D7.94.D7.9F_.D7.A2.D7.9C_.D7.94.D7.A9.D7.95.D7.9C.D7.97.D7.9F_.D7.A2.D7.A8.D7.95.D7.9A) in the introduction to his Nequdat Kesef, claiming that his objections to other scholars are meant only respectfully, I have heard it said that several of his remarks were rather caustic. Can anybody substantiate that claim? Preferably with references to passages within his various commentaries that can then be checked.

Comment: Congrats on your tumbleweed badge.

Comment: @Daniel - Ouch. Maybe I should rephrase the question :(

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27621/5

Comment: Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29601/5

Comment: There are a bunch of examples on this forum post: http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2660861&forum_id=19616 second post in the thread.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example from [Shakh Choshen Mishpat 85:7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=cm_x9525)

> וראיתי בספר גדולי תרומה ריש שער ל"ד דף קמ"ו שהאריך בפלפולים של הבל בעמוד א' וב' וג' ובקושיות בדברי הרמב"ם ושאר פוסקים ואין כדאי להשיב על דבריו כי לא ירד כלל להבין סוגית הש"ס והאמת בסוגית הש"ס ובדעת הרמב"ם כמו שכתבתי והם דברים ברורים ואמיתיים בלי ספק כלל
>
> And I have seen in the book *Gidulei Terumah* in the beginning of Gate 34, page 146, that he wrote at length with nonsensical casuistry in columns 1, 2, and 3, and with difficulties in the words of Rambam and the other decisors. And it is not worth it to respond to his words, for he did not penetrate at all to understand the Talmudic topic. And the truth of the Talmudic topic and the view of Rambam is as I have written, and [my words] are certain and true without any doubt.