# Why does Rashi translate שלולית differently from everyone else?

Tags: words, rashi, maseches-menachos, bava-kamma, masechet-peah

The [beginning of chapter 2 of *Pea*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&pgnum=155) says:

> These things divide a field [into two] for purposes of *pea* [requiring a separate *pea* from each subdivision]: …, a שלולית, ….

[The *Bavli*, *Bava Kama* 61:1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2910), cites a difference of opinion as what a שלולית is. According to one view, it's a gully or place where rainwater flows; according to the other, it's a main irrigation canal that, on overflowing, feeds side canals.

The commentaries on the *mishna* in *Pea* — [*Rash*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_ben_Abraham_of_Sens), [*Rambam*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides), [*Rav*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obadiah_ben_Abraham), [*P'ne Moshe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses_Margolies), [*Tif'eres Yisrael*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiferet_Yisrael_%28commentary%29), [*K'hati*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinchas_Kehati) — all accept the latter explanation: a שלולית is a main irrigation canal (some clarify that it's manmade) that feeds lesser canals on overflowing.

But *Rashi*, [*M'nachos* 71:2](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4531), says a שלולית is a rain gully. (*Rashbam*, [*Bava Basra* 55:1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3369), seems to agree.)

**Why does *Rashi* translate שלולית differently from almost everyone else?**

(Note that, whereas the aforementioned commentaries are commenting on the *mishna* itself, *Rashi* is commenting on the quotation of the *mishna* in a *g'mara*. [Maybe, then, the answer to my question is some way in which the context in *M'nachos* demands a different translation of שלולית.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30071) (Same for *Rashbam*, incidentally.) On the other hand, maybe the answer to my question is a difference of opinion about how to read the conclusion of the *g'mara* in *Bava Kama*. Or maybe something else.)

Comment: Perhaps Rashi explains it as a gully since [Bava Kama 61a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=61&format=pdf) says that if a gully separates, than an irrigation ditch surely separates. Therefore Rashi brings the opinion that includes both opinions, since he doesn't need/want to rule that one is correct.