# Vilna Gaon's Criticism of the Rambam

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, rambam, vilna-gaon

As mentioned in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15713/1659), the Vilna Gaon once criticised the Rambam for having been led astray by his own philosophy. I have seen this statement referenced also in [this article on Seforim Blog](http://seforim.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/the-vilna-gaon-part-1-how-modern-was-he.html) and in various articles by Rabbi Natan Slifkin ([such as this one](http://www.rationalistjudaism.com/2009/08/rambam-and-demons.html)). It seems to be fairly widely known, but I would like to see the Gaon's language, and I've not been able to find it online.

Since I don't currently have access to my seforim, can somebody please provide me with the text in question? Ideally, please also include the section of the Shulchan Arukh on which the Gra is commenting when he says it, and please include the full quote. With so many people making reference to it but nobody (it seems) actually providing the language, I am curious as to how unambiguous the Gra's criticism of the Rambam actually is.

Comment: This answerer has the precise reference http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27625/759

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57487/759

Comment: Tangentially, you might be interested in http://www.aishdas.org/asp/rambam-and-mesorah where I list other such condemnations (including what I believe is an anonymous one by the Maharal, and one by name in Sefer haBeris and another by RSRH. Then listing my own areas of discomfort (I can't pass judgment on the Rambam, just list ideas I don't see how they fit with Chazal's Judaism), starting in that post, but more in the next: http://www.aishdas.org/asp/akrasia

Comment: R' Nachman of Breslov also said the same thing. See [Chayei Moharan 407](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Moharan.407?lang=bi). There's a Chassidic source for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is in Beur HaGra to Yoreh De'ah ([179:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Beur_HaGra_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.179.13?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en))

> ואף על פי כו'. הרמב"ם וכ"כ בפי' המשנה לפ"ד דעבודת כוכבים אבל כל הבאים אחריו חלקו עליו **שהרי הרבה לחשים נאמרו בגמרא והוא נמשך אחר הפלוסופיא הארורה** ולכן כ' שכשפים ושמות ולחשים ושדים וקמיעות הכל הוא שקר **אבל כבר הכו אותו על קדקדו** שהרי מצינו הרבה מעשיות בגמ' ע"פ שמות וכשפים אמרה איהי מלתא ואסרתה לארבא אמרו כו' (שבת פ"א ב' חולין ק"ה ב') ובספ"ד מיתות ובירושלמי שם עובדא דר"א ור"י ובן בתירה וכן ר"ח ור"א דאיברו עיגלא תילתא ור' יהושע דאמר שם ואוקמיה בין שמיא לארעא (בכורות ח' ב') וכן אבישי בן צרויה (סנהדרין צ"ה א') והרבה כיוצא ואמרו (בספ"ד מיתות חולין ז' ב') למה נקרא שמן כשפים כו' והתורה העידה ויהיו תנינים וע' זוהר שם וכן קמיעין בהרבה מקומות ולחשים רבו מלספר. **והפלסופיא הטתו** ברוב לקחה לפרש הגמרא הכל בדרך הלציי ולעקור אותם מפשטן **וח"ו איני מאמין בהם ולא מהם ולא מהמונם** אלא כל הדברים הם כפשטן אלא שיש בהם פנימיות לא פנימיות של בעלי הפלוסופיא שזורקין אותו לאשפה שהם חצוניות אלא של בעלי האמת
>
> For many incantations are mentioned in the Talmud, and he was drawn after the accursed philosophy...But they already struck him on he crown of his head [i.e. violently rejected him]...And the philosophy led him astray...And heaven fore-fend! I do not do not believe in them at all. (My translation of the bolded portions).

He is commenting on the Shulchan Arukh's statement that whispering incantations over a wound is permissible even on Sabbath, even though it is not actually effective:

> מי שנשכו עקרב מותר ללחוש עליו, ואפילו בשבת, ואף על פי שאין הדבר מועיל כלום הואיל ומסוכן הוא התירו, כדי שלא תטרף דעתו עליו.

This is a quote from Rambam's [Hilkhot Avodah Zarah 11:12](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1411.htm).

As you can see, the criticism it quite unambiguous. Furthermore, the article you cite supports the authenticity of the comment, noting that:

> Its authenticity was attested to by R. Samuel Luria who examined that actual manuscript.

Comment: So the Gra is criticising the Rambam for not taking the Gemara about spells literally? Am I correct?        Can you explain this please "But they already struck him on he crown of his head [i.e. violently rejected him]"

Comment: I doubt that Rambam took the Gemara non-literally. Gra seems to indeed be saying Rambam took it non-literally. | He is saying Rambam totally rejected by his successors IIUC. I admit that the wording הכו _אותן_ על קדקדו is rather strange. One would expect the singular if it was referring to Rambam, or, if it were referring to his beliefs, one would expect the קדקדו would be the plural קדקדן. | I suspect there is a typo and it should read אותן, as in Sh'muel's link. | For similar usage by Gra, see ביאור הגר"א יורה דעה סימן רצג 
 וכבר **הכו על קדקדו כל האחרונים** ושגגה יצאה מתחת ידו @ElShteiger

Comment: To clarify gra assumes rambam read it non-literally. i assume he read it literally and rejected it @ElShteiger

Answer (score 4):

In [Yore Dea 179, 13](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5168)

> הרמב"ם וכ"כ בפי' המשנה לפ"ד דעבודת כוכבים אבל כל הבאים אחריו חלקו עליו שהרי הרבה לחשים נאמרו בגמרא והוא נמשך אחר הפלוסופיא ולכן כ׳ שכשפים ושמות ולחשים ושדים וקמיעות הכל הוא שקר אבל כבר הכו אותו על קדקדו שהרי מצינו הרבה מעשיות בגמ' ע"פ שמות וכשפים אמרה איהי מלתא ואסרתה לארבא אמרו כו׳ (שבת פ״א ב׳ חולין ק״ה ב׳) ובספ״ד מיתות ובירושלמי שם עובדא דר״א ור״י ובן בתירה וכן ר״ח ור״א דאיברו
>    עיגלא תילתא ור׳ יהושע דאמר שם ואוקמיה בין שמיא לארעא (בכורות ח׳ ב׳) וכן אבישי בן צרויה (סנהדרין צ״ח א׳) והרבה כיוצא ואמרו (בספ״ד מיתות חולין ז׳ ב׳) למה נקרא שמן
>    כשפים כו׳ והתורה העידה ויהיו תנינים וע׳ זוהר שם וכן קמיעין בהרבה מקומות ולחשים רבו מלספר. והפלסופיא הטתו ברוב לקחה לפרש הגמרא הכל בדרך הלציי ולעקור אותם
>    מפשטן וח״ו איני מאמין בהם ולא מהם ולא מהמונם אלא כל הדברים הם כפשטן אלא שיש בהם פנימיות לא פנימיות של בעלי הפלוסופיא שהם חצוניות אלא של בעלי האמת: ‏

The Vilna Gaon said that he views the stories in Chumash and Gemara in the literal way, and even though they have a "deeper" explanation, the true "inner meaning" is Kabbalistic, not philosophical.

Comment: I would translate the Gra as saying the true inner meaning in Qabbalistic, not Scholastic. I know the term is more obscure, but Qabbalah is itself a philosophy. In fact, it has large overlap with Platonism and neo-Platonism. When rabbis say "philosophy" they mean classical Greek philosophy, and in particular accepting it as an explanation of how the world works so solidly that one's Judaism has to accomodate that "reality". I.e. Scholasticism.

Comment: The point of literal way remains for me obscure,  what is really this literal way?